# Ajax form rework

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to change this ajax line into post form method `$.post()` for space optimisation and to insert some data into an object.

My ajax line :

```
 $("#login_button").click(function() {
        var username = $("#username").val().trim();
        var password = $("#password").val().trim();

        if (username != "" && password != "") {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'content/ajax/login.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    username: username,
                    password: password
                },
                success: function(response) {
                        var msg = "";
                        if (response == false) {
                            msg = dataJSON.error_message.wrong_password;
                        } else if (response == true) {
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                }


            });
        }
        return false; 
});
```

So i want it to be something like this :

```
$("#login_button").click(function() {
                var username = $("#username").val().trim();
                var password = $("#password").val().trim();
                //I added here "type" so i can handle few ajax calls in one php file by an if statement
                var post_data = { 'type' : 'login', 'username': username, 'password': password }

                    $.post('content/ajax/login.php', post_data, function(data) {
                            if(data == 'true') {
                            }
                            else if(data == 'false') {
                            }

                    });
});
```

What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: are you getting any errors? What makes you think there's something wrong?

Comment: yes, i think there is something wrong inside the post_data variable

Comment: What error (eg: error messages) are you getting?

Comment: its keeps reloading page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original code it has `return false` on the click handler. This prevents the elements default behaviour (in your case submitting the form).

You would want to do the same in the new function. Or add `event` parameter to the click handler function and use `event.preventDefault()`

For example

```
$("#login_button").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
})
```

Comment: I will test this now again